# scp outputs nonsense message and fails

Tags: macos, scp

SSH is totally working with this command:

```
$ ssh user@$THE_IP_ADDRESS
```

But when I try scp, I get this complete non-sense output

```
$ scp ~/file user@$THE_IP_ADDRESS:~/file
\033[?25l\033[?7l\033[0m\033[31m\033[1m            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

And the command fails. What does this message mean? Why can't I copy my file?

The client is a:

```
Darwin MacBook-Pro-4.local 17.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.4.0: Sun Dec 17 09:19:54 PST 2017; root:xnu-4570.41.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

And the server is a:

```
Linux cortex-deus 4.13.0-36-generic #40~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 23:25:58 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Those look like escape codes that tell your terminal emulator to do things like set the text color. What happens if you add `-v` (up to `-vvv`) to that `scp` command line? Post the resulting verbose/debug output so we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out my `.bashrc` broke it. My `.bashrc` calls [neofetch](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch) on login to print some styled ascii art. That `.-/+oossssoo+/-.` is part of the ascii art and the other stuff is escape codes for colors and such. I fixed it by not printing anything on login.

EDIT: But if you insist on echoing fancy stuff like ascii art on login, you can guard your commands with `if [[ $- =~ "i" ]]` which checks if the session is interactive.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same problem.
The problem is caused by the neofetch call at start of terminal session.
Fixed by this in my .bashrc :

```
if [[ $- != *i* ]]; then
    return;
else
    if [ -x /usr/bin/neofetch ]; then
        neofetch
    fi
fi
```